# My question can't be answered, there is no answer for it

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have posted this question: [PayPal button with 'min_amount' AND 'set_customer_limit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025801/paypal-button-with-min-amount-and-set-customer-limit)

After the technical PayPal support has answered my ticket, the case is simple & clear: there is no way resolving the problem the way I want to. I have to implement it a complete different way, which makes my question obsolete. Now, shall I:

- delete the question?
- give an answer explaining that there is no answer?
- other possibilities?

the question has no votes, not much visitors (and no answers ;-).

Comment: Is is possible for you to answer your own question with the "complete different way" that you solved the problem?

Comment: @TecBrat What do you mean by *"complete different way"*?

Comment: I thought I had looked before I commented. I was just quoting you. Now I see you already did what I was trying to suggest. Basically my comment was a much belated, short version of the answer by "amit". I don't know how I failed to see it was already answered.

Comment: You misinterpret answer and solution. Your question has an answer. But it does not have a solution the way you do it.

Comment: thx for pointing at. I've putted the word solution inside quotation marks...

Comment: @pc-shooter: btw, mentioning it here got you some visitors and votes, for it seems a well-posed question.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

In my opinion, you should answer your own question. Mention that there is no answer to the question, according to the PayPal team, and include the solution you ended up doing as work-around to your problem.

This kind of question and answer might be a very helpful contribution for future readers that will come across the same problem later on.

P.S. as an example usage of this technique, I did it myself when realizing [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11482108/572670) doesn't really have an answer. I wrote why there is no answer, and offered a workaround I ended up doing.

Comment: Thank you! I'll post my workaround, also mentioning that for future projects, using the PayPal API is the better solution, even if the docs  are a bit a pain in the ...

Comment: I guess you may also accept your own answer.

Comment: @Jérôme yess, but only tomorrow... and as it's quick & dirty, I'm not sure if I should ;-)

Comment: @pc-shooter - (your answer looks ok to me)... maybe your should review and "propose edits" till you as questioner are satisfied :)... More practical approach would be to get answer in shape you are remotely ok with, accept and later edit it if question gets any attention.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Not sure if I'm getting you right, (probably already too much dazed about all that PayPal stuff), but how do I do a review and propose edits?  ...With a moderation flag, maybe?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov And WHat do you mean by *...More practical approach would be to get answer in shape you are remotely ok with,...*? Sorry, but I don't get it. I need a break!

Comment: @pc-shooter - I tried to put smiley at the end... The same way as you'd work on any of your own code if working alone - read it as someone else wrote it, mark questionable places, go back and edit... repeat till both parts of you (editor and reviewer) are happy (Also as I said the way answer is now is better than many of accepted answers, so additional work is *not required*)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov lol... ok, Yes I DO definitely need a break ;-)

Comment: @pc-shooter One problem with these types of answers is that they can fairly easily become obsolete. What's not possible today might be possible at some point in the future. I would try to include a version number that it applies to in the answer. Or at least a date, if there is no specific version number. I sometimes write something like "this is not supported in the latest released version (7.42) of ABC." This way, future readers can tell how current the information is, without picking apart the edit history.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I totally agree with you. The API has naturally a version number, but not the hosted buttons feature, so I'll put a date in the answer.

Comment: Surely, "There is no answer for this question", is a completely legitimate answer :)