# Add option to close question because there is no answer/problem

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, self-answer

I sometimes ask a question for which there might be no answer - for instance my latest question [ACRA send report without exiting app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31555848/928952). 

 While I was updating my answer, to give more information, I found my problem to be artificial (i.e. self-made). The code itself was good, and working as it was supposed to.

Now I'd like to close the question, since answering doesn't make sense, because the correct answer is in the question. The `close` options that exist now don't support something like `answer in question`. I could remove the question, but I do think the question itself is meaningful/helpful.

Although my question looks like [My question can't be answered, there is no answer for it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292381/928952) it's different in that the answer in my case is in the question, but the problem was artificial...

Comment: Post your solution as an answer instead of editing it into the question

Answer (score 4):

Does this stock close reason not work for you?

> This question was caused by a **problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: You're right. I'll keep that one in mind. The thing is I think the code snippet  might be meaningful...